# D'où vient l'expression québécoise: « Chauffer » son automobile

Tags: expressions, québec

Au Québec, ou en tout cas, à Trois-Rivières, j'ai quelques fois entendu l'expression:

> Il est bien trop saoul pour *chauffer* son char!

Quelle est la provenance du mot « chauffer »? Je comprends qu'il veut dire conduire, mais je ne comprend pas pourquoi nous utilisons ce mot.

Quelqu'un en a une idée?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Chauffer une voiture* vient de l'utilisation des bougies sur les premières automobiles. Il fallait chauffer les bougies à l'aide d'une flamme quelques minutes avant de démarrer. Cette tâche était dévolue au ... *chauffeur* !

Ce chauffeur, héritier direct du chauffeur de chaudière à vapeur, avait une tâche bien réduite par rapport à celui dont il avait pris le nom. Le chauffeur d'une chaudière devait maintenir la température du feu et la pression de la vapeur de façon à produire l'énergie ensuite utilisée pour faire avancer une locomotive ou faire fonctionner des machines.

On ne chauffe plus les bougies avec une flamme, la bougie de préchauffage est désormais électrique et automatique, on continue cependant d'attendre le temps nécessaire pour qu'elle fasse effet avant de lancer le démarreur:

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://golf4panne.blogspot.com/2010/08/caler-brutalement-avec-le-voyant.html)</sup>

Chauffeur est resté en usage, mais désigne aujourd'hui le conducteur. Chauffer une voiture c'est la conduire (c'est la même chose pour la locomotive).

---

Dans un moteur diesel, l'air est comprimé dans un cylindre par un piston et poussé en bout de cylindre où le carburant est injecté (atomisé dans l'air comprimé) pour provoquer une explosion spontanée.

Pour que ceci fonctionne, le mélange air-carburant doit être porté à une certaine température, de l'ordre de 800°C, qui ne peut être atteinte du seul fait de l'échauffement provoqué par la compression de l'air. Ce n'est pas un problème lorsque le moteur est déjà chaud, en revanche une petite aide est nécessaire au départ.

La bougie assure le préchauffage du mélange (parfois seulement du carburant) lors du démarrage à froid. Une fois le moteur lancé, les explosions sont capable de maintenir la température voulue.

- Bougie de préchauffage moderne: [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bougie_de_pr%C3%A9chauffage).

Une bougie de préchauffage diesel se présente sous la forme d'un crayon chauffant:

[image]
<sup>Source: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AENXSzqKQF4)</sup>

Si la bougie moderne est électrique, celle des premiers moteurs diesel était une tige horizontale traversant la paroi du cylindre avec une partie émergente externe. Cette dernière était chauffée à l'aide d'une chaudière.

[image]
<sup>Brûleurs à gaz et parties externes des bougies sur une Peugeot Type 15 restaurée</sup>

- Type 15 sur [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peugeot_Type_15)

Chaque piston avait sa propre bougie avec sa chaudière extérieure. Le chauffeur d'une voiture était l'employé — à cette époque une voiture était un luxe pour gens aisés — chargé de chauffer les bougies avant le départ.

Comment: En 2015, le site web de la Cité de l'automobile de Mulhouse [indiquait](https://web.archive.org/web/20150123180917/http://www.citedelautomobile.com/fr/un-peu-dhistoire/le-saviez-vous) que « Les premiers véhicules automobiles routiers sont à vapeur et leurs conducteurs doivent eux aussi faire chauffer l'eau de la chaudière. C’est donc le terme de chauffeur qui est spontanément repris pour les désigner. ». Peux-tu stp. préciser ta source.

Answer (score 6):

Comme on l'a [mentionné](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13827), de « [chauffeur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chauffeur) », « *[c]elui qui s'occupe du feu d'une forge, d'un fourneau, du fonctionnement d'une chaudière.* » du 17e (*TLFi*), éventuellement étendu à la locomotive au 19e, par exemple le *chauffeur-mécanicien* (assez différent des chauffeurs d'*Orgerès*), puis fin 19e à l'automobile par similarité des fonctions, pour [*conducteur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conducteur) du véhicule automobile, même si on doit rappeler la [différence](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2068246) entre l'appellation d'emploi et le rôle. On a semble-t-il même « [*chauffer à la mitaine*](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?no=382&base=QU) » pour la boîte manuelle. On ne se surprendra pas donc que le verbe [chauffer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chauffer) comme tel ait aussi des sens reliés à la mécanique locomotive (« En allumer les chaudières, mettre en service. », « Avoir ses machines qui fonctionnent, en particulier pour le départ. » - *TLFi*). Et au [Québec](http://www.wikebec.org/chauffer/definition/) couramment pour « conduire l'automobile »; pas nécessairement [recensé](https://archive.org/stream/leparlerpopulair00dionuoft#page/138/mode/2up) au début du 20e.

Comment: Effectivement, j'ai souvent entendu aussi le "Chauffer à la mitaine" pour quelqu'un conduisant avec une boîte manuelle.

Comment: @SimonDugré Je l'ai entendu peu souvent, on aime bien parler des rapports, mais je l'aurais compris. Le train ça donne un peu un nouveau sens à qqc. comme « _j'étais en train de chauffer mon 8 sur la 20, pis là, une "van" et un pointillé, ça fait que je te l'ai "tapé"_ !». Merci!

Answer (score 2):

Je crois qu'il s'agirait probablement ici d'un [verbe dénominal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_d%C3%A9nominal) dérivé du nom *chauffeur*. Un autre possibilité (qui me semble moins probable) serait une dérivation à partir de l'expression *faire chauffer le moteur*.

Comment: Le Multidictionnaire le classe d'archaîsme, je me demande donc si *faire chauffer le moteur* est plus probable, surtout qu'il fait plus froid en hiver au Québec qu'en Europe.

Comment: Personnellement, je ne le classerait pas comme archaïque, mais peut-être bien comme vieilli.